# Populate DataTextField with "Example Name | Example Number"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatextfield

I have a SQL select statement and using the results I bind it to an asp dropdown.

```
String strQuery ="SELECT RTRIM(NAME), NUMBER . . ." 

customerselect.DataTextField = "NAME+ ' | ' +NUMBER";
```

I need to display in the DataTextField:

```
Example Name | 123456
```

I'm getting an error:

> " does not contain a property with the name 'NAME+ ' | ' +NUMBER'."

Answer (score 2):

The `DataTextField` property specifies which field from your data source to use as the text label for the drop-down, not the actual text string itself.  So, if you wanted the drop-down to have that particular format, you might try something like the following:

```
String strQuery = "SELECT RTRIM(NAME) + ' | ' +
    CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR(32)) AS Label, NUMBER AS Value . . .";

// Run the query and do the appropriate data binding here

customerselect.DataTextField = "Label";
```

Additional info on the DataTextField property can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
customerselect.DataTextField = string.Format("{0}+ | +{1}", Name, Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your function result an alias.  In other words, change this:

```
String strQuery ="SELECT RTRIM(NAME), NUMBER . . ."
```

to this:

```
String strQuery ="SELECT RTRIM(NAME) as name, NUMBER . . ."
```